# CS0535 C# 'Service1' does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm following the tutorial below to add a web service for a mobile app:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nikitakova/how-to-create-wcf-rest-service-for-mobile-app/

the problem is whenever I run the project it shows me error messages as below:

[image: error message]
and the images below show my codes:

[image: the interface]

[image: public class]

Any ideas of how to solve such issue??

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the solution? With extensions such as resharper, VS often gives me errors such as these and it generally helps me provided that there isn't an obvious error and my code is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already figured the error, I have created a new class to inherit from IService, while I have to use the class Service that is already exist.